# Importing user classes in Java

Tags: java, class, import

I have a class called CSV.java and I want to import it into another class.
The class CSV.java is located in another folder as the class I want to use it in (Main.java).

On my computer I currently have a folder called 'java'
inside it there is 2 folders: Classes and Assignment
in Classes I have a folder called 'CSV' which contains CSV.java nad CSV.class
inside Assingment I have Main.java.

Is there a way to import CSV.java without having to copy it over?

In CSV.java I do have `package CSV`

Comment: Package and class both having the same name?!

Comment: this is basic, read this tutorial http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/usepkgs.html

Answer (score 1):

From what you say, you can

```
import CSV.CSV;
```

However, if you have an IDE, it can automatically add imports for you.

Comment: It says package CSV.CSV does not exist

Comment: Your CSV.class must be under a directory CSV. i.e. it has to have the same directory structure for the `.class` as the `.java`

Comment: Again, using an IDE would ensure that files and paths are all correct.

Answer (score 0):

This is what `import` is for.  Your Main class should probably look something like

```
package Assignment;
import CSV.CSV;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String [ ] args) {
       CSV csv = new CSV();
       // Whatever you're doing with the csv object...
    }

    // Other methods

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import CSV.CSV;
```

Note that `CSV` class must be declared as *public* in CSV.java

```
public class CSV { ...
```

Then you can use the CSV methods in your class like:

```
CSV.method_from_CSV.java(..);  // static method
```

or create a new CSV object and use its public methods

```
CSV csv = new CSV(); 
csv.method_from_CSV.java(..);    // non-static method
```

Answer (score 0):

Additional information: Package names are lowercase by convention.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `classpath` (cp) switch for compiling (javac.exe) and executing (java.exe).

compile CSV.java

```
c:\java\classes>javac CSV.java -d .
```

Main.java

```
package assignment;
public class Main
{
   public static void main(String []args)
    {
        CSV.CSV csv=new CSV.CSV();
    }
}
```

Compile the Main.java

```
c:\java\assignment>javac -cp .;c:\java\classes Main.java -d .
```

To run,

```
c:\java\assignment>java -cp .;c:\java\classes assignment.Main
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this in Eclipse?

Comment: No! Its from command prompt. You didn't mentioned IDE eclipse in your question.